# No Such method Exception while running SpringTest with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am unable to run the tests for my DAOImpl class using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) & getting following exception:
No such method exception.
Please refer to the image from eclipse screeshot below:

[image]

I suspect this could be because of the repository-test.xml configuration file placed at wrong location & spring is not able to pick it from the classpath location for @ContextConfiguration annotation & load the configurations from this file.
Can some one please tell me if i placed the configuration test file correctly under the project ?

Following is my repository-test.xml located under "WebContent/WEB-INF/spring/"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.braziljs.loiane" />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- misc -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
        <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/braziljs</value></property>
        <property name="username"><value>root</value></property>
       <!-- <property name="password"><value>root</value></property>-->
    </bean>

     <!-- Configures Hibernate - Database Config --> <!--  import resource="db-config.xml" /> -->


</beans>
```

And here is the Spring Test class:

```
package br.com.braziljs.loiane.test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
//import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import br.com.braziljs.loiane.dao.DeviceDAO;
import br.com.braziljs.loiane.model.MIDevice;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration 
@ContextConfiguration("/WEB-INF/spring/repository-test.xml")
public class TestDeviceDao {

    /* @Autowired
     private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;*/


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    //  this.deviceRepository = new DeviceDAO(ds);
        System.out.println("inside setup");
    }

    /*

    @Autowired
    private DeviceDAO deviceRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;
    */


    @Test
    public void test() {
    //  when(hibernateTemplate.get(Book.class, 1L)).thenReturn(new Book());

    //  final MIDevice  device = deviceRepository.findByDeviceId(1L);

    //  verify(hibernateTemplate, times(1)).get(Book.class, 1L);
    //  assertNotNull(device);
    //  System.out.println(device);
        System.out.println("inside setup");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: This is most likely a classpath issue, not a spring configuration issue.  Make sure that every dependancy in your pom.xml file is also in your .classpath file

Comment: Stacktrace & exception are in the attached screenshot image from Eclipse. I suspect this could be due to classpath not picking up the file